# Tried to upload file but it keep showing invalid file

Tags: php, upload

uploadfile.php

```
<?php
 $allowedExts = array("doc", "pdf");
 $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
 if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/doc")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/pdf"))
 && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 500000000)
 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
   {
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
     {
     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
     }
   else
     {
     echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
     echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
     echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
     echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
       "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
       }}
      else { echo "Invalid file";

   }

 ?>
```

uploader.php

```
<form action="uploadfile.php" method="post"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Not sure why, I tried to upload file but it keep showing invalid file after i click upload.
I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: can you post your upload form aswell? The `name` of your file input must be `file` according to your code but just want to make sure. You should maybe modify it so that the first `else` is `else if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0)` then have a final else rather than two `else` statments.

Comment: Using [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) is cleaner than `end(explode())`.

Comment: why dont you var_dump $_FILES["file"]? I think that can give you a good start/hint.

Answer (score 0):

A common pitfall is the missing enctype attribute in your form. If you want to upload a file, your  should be something like the following.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add some debug out put like: echo $extension; To check if you got the right part of the filename. print_r($_FILES) may also help. If this still dosn't help try to put each part of the if statement in a seperate "if" so you can check which one fails.